# SwiftUI: How to make network request after tapping button in List (custom row view)?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, swiftui, social-networking

I'm recreating functionality similar to a "Follow" button, like that on Instagram. 1. On button tap, send a follow or unfollow request, and toggle the state of the button.

Problem: 
I have a Follow button in a custom row view in a list, and for the life of me, I can't figure out how and where to make the network request and manage the model's state.

Desired Functionality: 
1. User taps "Follow" 
2. Send a network request to follow User and toggle button state from "Follow" to "Unfollow"
3. If error, flip button back to original state (maybe display error, not critical) by modifying the model 
4. If success, do nothing because state change was optimistically performed after (2.)

For the sake of simplicity, I simplified models and views. Here's what I have

```
struct UserRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user: User

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // 1. The user object has an ID property, which I'll need for the network request
            // 2. Do I handle state management, and send network request here? Seems strange from a List's cell.
        }) {
            Text(user.isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow")
        }
        .background(user.isFollowing ? Color.green : Color.red)
    }
}
```

And the List...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userManager = UserManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List() {
                Section(header:
                    Text("USERS")
                ) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< userManager.users.count, id: \.self) {
                        // Do I pass a closure to UserRowView, so I can access the
                        // UserManager() instance? If so, how do I get the index of the
                        // cell containing the button?
                        UserRowView(user: self.userManager.users[$0])
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My questions are noted inline in both code blocks.

Thanks